# Getting ScrollPosition of this AppBar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to get the scrollPosition of the element stores in aboutSection but it always returns null even though, I have the id about. Any ideas ?

```
const aboutSection = document.getElementById('#about').scrollTop;

<TheAppBar position={scrollPosition > aboutSection ? "fixed" : "static"} id="about">
```

Comment: does the `#about` element have a CSS `overflow` property that enables a vertical scrollbar such as `auto` or `scroll`?

Comment: While bad practice, do you have more than one element in the page with id="about"

Comment: no I only have one about ID